# Neo4J relationships modelling issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to model inter-city and intra-city relationships based on the following hierarchy:

```
domestic travel/
├── intra-city/
│   ├── bangalore
│   ├── pune
│   ├── hyderabad
│   ├── delhi
│   ├── mumbai
│   ├── kolkata
│   └── chennai
├── inter-city/
│   ├── bangalore -> pune
│   └── bangalore -> hyderabad
│   └── bangalore -> chennai
│   └── bangalore -> delhi
│   └── bangalore -> mumbai
│   └── bangalore -> kolkata
│   └── hyderabad -> bangalore
│   └── hyderabad -> pune
│   └── hyderabad -> chennai
│   └── hyderabad -> delhi
│   └── hyderabad -> mumbai
│   └── hyderabad -> kolkata
```

Where domestic travel is my root node which can children nodes

- Intracity (Travel within the same city)
- Intercity (Travel between two
  different cities)

I also have a cities root node which has all the cities attached to it.

---

Currently I am modelling it as having 2 relations **(:FROM_CITY and :TO_CITY)**:

If the travel type is intracity then I'm directly marking `:TO_CITY` relation to the city and if its intercity I am taking the first city as marking the relation `:FROM_CITY`. This is depicted by the below screenshot.

[image]

---

**Below are the Cypher Queries I'm using to model the relations.**

**1) Travel tree:**

```
MERGE (Travel: TravelType { name: 'Travel' })
ON CREATE SET
    Travel.id = randomUUID(),
    Travel.type = 'TravelType',
    Travel.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Travel.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (InternationTravel:TravelType { name: 'InternationTravel' })
ON CREATE SET
    InternationTravel.id = randomUUID(),
    InternationTravel.type = 'TravelType',
    InternationTravel.subtype = 'Internation Travel',
    InternationTravel.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    InternationTravel.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (DomesticTravel:TravelType { name: 'DomesticTravel' })
ON CREATE SET
    DomesticTravel.id = randomUUID(),
    DomesticTravel.type = 'TravelType',
    DomesticTravel.subtype = 'Domestic Travel',
    DomesticTravel.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    DomesticTravel.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (IntraCity: TravelType { name: 'IntraCity' })
ON CREATE SET
    IntraCity.id = randomUUID(),
    IntraCity.type = 'Domestic Travel',
    IntraCity.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    IntraCity.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (InterCity: TravelType { name: 'InterCity' })
ON CREATE SET
    InterCity.id = randomUUID(),
    InterCity.type = 'Domestic Travel',
    InterCity.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    InterCity.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Travel)-[:OF_TYPE_TRAVEL]->(DomesticTravel)
MERGE (Travel)-[:OF_TYPE_TRAVEL]->(InternationTravel)

MERGE (DomesticTravel)-[:OF_TYPE_DOMESTIC_TRAVEL]->(IntraCity)
MERGE (DomesticTravel)-[:OF_TYPE_DOMESTIC_TRAVEL]->(InterCity)
RETURN *
```

---

**2) Cities tree:**

```
MERGE (City: Location { name: 'City' })
ON CREATE SET
    City.id = randomUUID(),
    City.type = 'Location',
    City.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    City.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Bangalore:Location { name: 'Bangalore' })
ON CREATE SET
    Bangalore.id = randomUUID(),
    Bangalore.type = 'Location',
    Bangalore.created = timestamp(),
    Bangalore.IATACode = 'BLR',
    Bangalore.CityType = 1
ON MATCH SET
    Bangalore.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Chennai:Location { name: 'Chennai' })
ON CREATE SET
    Chennai.id = randomUUID(),
    Chennai.type = 'Location',
    Chennai.created = timestamp(),
    Chennai.IATACode = 'MAA',
    Chennai.CityType = 1
ON MATCH SET
    Chennai.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Hyderabad:Location { name: 'Hyderabad' })
ON CREATE SET
    Hyderabad.id = randomUUID(),
    Hyderabad.type = 'Location',
    Hyderabad.created = timestamp(),
    Hyderabad.IATACode = 'HYD',
    Hyderabad.CityType = 1
ON MATCH SET
    Hyderabad.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Pune:Location { name: 'Pune' })
ON CREATE SET
    Pune.id = randomUUID(),
    Pune.type = 'Location',
    Pune.created = timestamp(),
    Pune.IATACode = 'PNQ',
    Pune.CityType = 1
ON MATCH SET
    Pune.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (DelhiNCR:Location { name: 'DelhiNCR' })
ON CREATE SET
    DelhiNCR.id = randomUUID(),
    DelhiNCR.type = 'Location',
    DelhiNCR.created = timestamp(),
    DelhiNCR.IATACode = 'DEL',
    DelhiNCR.CityType = 2
ON MATCH SET
    DelhiNCR.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Mumbai:Location { name: 'Mumbai' })
ON CREATE SET
    Mumbai.id = randomUUID(),
    Mumbai.type = 'Location',
    Mumbai.created = timestamp(),
    Mumbai.IATACode = 'BOM',
    Mumbai.CityType = 2
ON MATCH SET
    Mumbai.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (Kolkata:Location { name: 'Kolkata' })
ON CREATE SET
    Kolkata.id = randomUUID(),
    Kolkata.type = 'Location',
    Kolkata.created = timestamp(),
    Kolkata.IATACode = 'CCU',
    Kolkata.CityType = 2
ON MATCH SET
    Kolkata.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (`Other Cities`:Location { name: 'Other Cities' })
ON CREATE SET
    `Other Cities`.id = randomUUID(),
    `Other Cities`.type = 'Location',
    `Other Cities`.created = timestamp(),
    `Other Cities`.IATACode = [],
    `Other Cities`.CityType = 3
ON MATCH SET
    `Other Cities`.lastUpdated = timestamp()

MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Chennai)

MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(Kolkata)

MERGE (City)-[:OF_TYPE_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (Bangalore)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (Hyderabad)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (Pune)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (Chennai)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (DelhiNCR)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (Mumbai)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
MERGE (Kolkata)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)

MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
MERGE (`Other Cities`)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
RETURN *
```

---

**3) Linking Intracity and Intercity travel to Cities tree:**

```
MATCH (IntraCity: TravelType { name: 'IntraCity' })
MATCH (InterCity: TravelType { name: 'InterCity' })
MATCH (Bangalore: Location { name: 'Bangalore' })
MATCH (Hyderabad:Location { name: 'Hyderabad' })
MATCH (Chennai: Location { name: 'Chennai' })
MATCH (Pune: Location { name: 'Pune' })
MATCH (DelhiNCR: Location { name: 'DelhiNCR' })
MATCH (Mumbai: Location { name: 'Mumbai' })
MATCH (Kolkata: Location { name: 'Kolkata' })
MATCH (`Other Cities`: Location { name: 'Other Cities' })
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Bangalore)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(Bangalore)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(Hyderabad)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Chennai)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(Chennai)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Pune)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(DelhiNCR)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Mumbai)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(Mumbai)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(Kolkata)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(Kolkata)
CREATE (IntraCity)-[:TO_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)
CREATE (InterCity)-[:FROM_CITY]->(`Other Cities`)
RETURN *
```

---

> **The issue I am facing is its quickly becoming out of hand to manage and query these nodes and relationships. As a result I am not able to
>   properly query it. 
>   Is there a better way to model inter-city and intra-city travel between cities, you can point to any obvious mistakes I am making.**

Any suggestions will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: While you've provided the queries to create the graph, you haven't provided details of the use cases that will drive the queries you want to make on such a graph. Without knowing what kind of use cases and the questions you plan on asking of your graph, we can't provide recommendations.

Comment: @InverseFalcon it will be used a FAQ chatbot which will answer queries like `I want to take my car to city a to city b what will be my reimbursement`

Comment: @InverseFalcon what do you think about it?

Comment: I think we still need to know more. How is reimbursement supposed to work? Is it based on the distance between cities, or some flat rate if it's intra-city, or does that depend on which city? Is this travel by road only? Does time or scheduling matter? Is the cost the same between cities if you're going in the opposite direction? Will you only ever be looking for pricing info between (max) 2 cities at a time? Any additional info would be helpful

Comment: Also is this graph meant to span countries, or just work within India? If it spans countries, would a trip that crosses a country border have a modified cost based on crossing countries, or is it still a distance-based cost?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Its the same rate between cities, where it is Rs8 per km, this graph is meant to work within cities of india.

Comment: Okay, and how is intracity calculation supposed to work? Is intracity travel calculation only meant to happen within the context of a single city, where you'll never calculate intra-city travel when traveling between cities? Is the rate always the same?